# Error "The caller does not have permission" when trying to save a query in BigQuery Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have created a project in BigQuery and I am currently exporting GA4 data.  I wrote a query to view data and now I want to save it.  When I do I receive an error stating "The caller does not have permission."  I have the below permissions atm.

BigQuery Admin
BigQuery User
Code Creator
Dataform Admin
Owner

I have tried to give myself more permissions.  I basically have every permission atm and I still can't get the save to work.

Comment: I've been getting this error today too. I've not gotten this error in the past. I am the project owner and have completed the steps in the official docs. They may have a bug? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/work-with-saved-queries

Answer (score 0):

1. Check IAM Permissions: Ensure your user account has the necessary IAM permissions.
   bigquery.tables.create: To save the result as a table.
   bigquery.jobs.create: To run the query jobs.
   Verify that the permissions are granted at the project, dataset, or table level as necessary.
2. Dataset Permissions: Check if the dataset you are trying to save the table into has the correct permissions.
   Ensure you have WRITER or OWNER access to the dataset.
3. Destination Table:
   Ensure that the destination table or dataset isn't in a different project where you may not have the necessary permissions.
4. Cache and Cookies:
   Sometimes, a simple browser cache issue could cause unexpected errors. Try using an incognito window or a different browser.

If the above still doesn't work review the Audit Logs in the Google Cloud Console to get more details about the error.

Comment: Do you see any audit logs pertaining to saved queries? I don't see any entries when I successfully update a saved query. Creating a new one gives the same errors as the OP but I don't see that reflected in any audit log.

Comment: I was able to get it to work today.  I guess it took a while to get the permissions to get set.  I had waited a few hours and still nothing.  I guess it takes a while for them to go through

Comment: @Mike I still have my original permissions and I now receive no error when saving a query now. I believe this must have been a service interruption or bug they either rolled back or fixed.